# iPhone/iPad universal app will not build for iPhone

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, universal, uisplitview

I have made my application universal for iPhone and iPad (window-based application; universal) from scratch.
First I made all logic and views for iPhone and it worked. After that I created views for iPad. That worked to. But when I implemented UISplitViewController or UIPopover, the application will not build anymore for iPhone.

I call my custom splitViewController like that:

```
MySplitViewController *mySplitViewController = [[MySplitViewController" alloc] init];
```

Class definition looks like that:
@interface MySplitViewController : UISplitViewController {
}

On build (for iPhone 3.1.3) it gives me this error:

> cannot find interface declaration for
>   'UISplitViewController', superclass of
>   'MySplitViewController'

Afcourse, SDK 3.1.3 does not contain all new features from SDK 3.2. That's clear. So I tried creating instance of my class like that:

```
MySplitViewController *mySplitViewController = [[NSClassFromString(@"MySplitViewController") alloc] init];
```

It still gives me the same error.

I also tried to weak-link framework but that helped neither.

What I also tried is that I wrap creating instance of class in parentheses like that:

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController");
if (cls != nil) {
    MySplitViewController *mySplitViewController = [[NSClassFromString(@"MySplitViewController") alloc] init];
}
```

Could please someone tells me how can I call specific classes so I can run my application for both platform ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html).

I hope it will helps someone else...